# Selenium :- In my application there is button whose id is getting randomly generated, How to locate that button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

In my web application there are 5 buttons in the page which having the same title, name and the id is getting generated randomly, How to click on the particular button,which properties can i use, so thats its work fine in IE.

Comment: Could you add HTML snippet for the buttons, it would be helpful in answering the question

Comment: <tr><td><a href="#" title="Add a Web Part (opens in new window)" onclick="MSOLayout_ShowQuickAddDialog('a85b4cc6-dcea-41ce-88a6-6b0e4fad1a6a','22b116a3-0f55-42bc-81b2-b0e2534eea09','Default',false,3,50,QuickAddDialogCallbackcpartgallerypickerpage.aspx','resizable=yes,status=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,directories=no,location=no,width=700px,height=700px');;event.cancelBubble=true;" style="text-decoration:none;"><nobr><img align="middle" border="0" alt="Add a Web Part (opens in new window)" src="/_layouts/images/wpqaicon.gif" />&nbsp;<span>Add a Web Part</span></nobr></a></td></tr>

Comment: This is the HTML for one button.. There are four buttons with same content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium will be able to locate the element using various methods - 
1. id,
2. name,
3. xpath,
4. css id.
The best practice would be to add a name to that element and then let the id be generated randomly. You can then identify the element by name(if you are using selenium plugin for firefox, record a test case and go to that element and the plugin will give you options to chose another identifier if you wish to). But in most cases of dynamic web pages, selenium starts looking for the element even before it's generated or loaded. The trick is to ask selenium to wait till the element/page is loaded completely. You can use waitForElementPresent() method. This method will solve 90% of your problems

Answer (score 1):

Use Xpath or CSS path.
See Selenium reference(http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.2/reference.html) and scroll down to where it says "Element Locators" for other types of selectors you can use.

Comment: Please help me to find the CSS or Xpath locator of above code.. As i am not able to get correct one.. The Id for Button is getting change everytime. and The title and other properties are same for all four buttons

Comment: for all 3 buttons is the content of Span different if it is different den try this    //div[span=" content "]/following-sibling::div//span[.="content"]

Comment: or You can use //a[@src='/_layouts/images/wpqaicon.gif']